# Laravel 4 add routes to resource controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I have a resource controller with all basic routes implemented

- create
- store
- update
- delete
- index
- show

But I need one more route like '/controllerName/otherRoute'... how do I create one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add that one extra additional route the same as you would any other.

```
Route::get('another-route', 'ControllerName@anotherRoute');
```

Comment: but i cant do it via controller?

Comment: There is no special way to add additional routes to a resource controller. Just define it as you would a traditional route, like I said.